# How can I rebuild search index of Elasticsearch in Django automatically on docker startup?

Tags: django, bash, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

It's my first time using Elasticsearch with Django on Docker and I realize that every time I start docker-compose, I have to issue `./manage.py search_index --rebuild` to index all my documents in Elasticsearch.
I've been trying to do this automatically but still doesn't seem to work. My `web` service command looks like this:

```
web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 && sleep 60 && python manage.py search_index --rebuild"
    
    ...
```

I added `sleep 60` so that it can wait for Elasticsearch to start up before issuing the rebuild command. And even with that, nothing happens unless I explicitly issue it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second and third commands in the `&&` chain will only run after the first one has exited, meaning after the webserver has been stopped. You'll have to add another service just for this task.

```
rebuild_index:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "sleep 60 && python manage.py search_index --rebuild"
    restart: on-failure
```

Better yet, instead of sleeping, you can `depend_on` the Elasticsearch service. Am not 100% sure this will work, please post your results if you try it.

```
rebuild_index:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py search_index --rebuild"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
        elasticsearch:
            condition: service_started
```

Comment: Yeah, this works and I'm also trying to interact with the shell. I thought adding `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true` would do that but it didn't. Have any idea how I can make that happen too?

Comment: Sorry, not sure about what you are trying to achieve. You may be better opening new questions for that. Please *accept* the answer if that was helpful

Comment: There's a prompt that comes up after the command

Comment: `python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f` is what you are looking for. `-f` jumps the prompt interaction

Answer (score 0):

#### NOT WORKING

So, using @Alexandr Tatarinov answer I was able to achive automatic index rebuild.
Im docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: pgdb
  es:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    container_name: es
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres   
    container_name: drf
    depends_on:
      - db
      - es
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
  rebuild_index:
    build: .
    container_name: rebuild_index
    command: python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
        web:
          condition: service_healthy
        es:
          condition: service_healthy
```

using `healthcheck` we are able to define if our containers are running, in particular we need to check the `web` container (my Django app) and the `es` container (my elasticsearch)

`depends_on` instruction on the `rebuild_index` container will wait for `web` and `es` containers to be operative. then it will execute the command.
`-f` will jump the prompt interaction while we must configure with `environment` the database info needed to make the command work.

#### EDIT - WORKING VERSION

for some reason the container `rebuild_index` starts and run is command with no errors but do not generate the indexes properly... I think that the reason is because the command needs to be launched on the same container.

so, a cleaner and **working** version:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: pgdb
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
  es:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.2
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    container_name: es
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres   
    container_name: drf
    depends_on:
        db:
          condition: service_healthy
        es:
          condition: service_healthy
```